# Por que não consigo passar o name="" do summernote via ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Depois de alguns teste vi que o summernote não passa o name="" via requisição ajax, alguém sabe me dizer o por que disso?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#submit_btn', function(){
        var titulo = $('#titulo').val();
        var dica = $('#dica').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'salvar_dica.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'save': 1,
                'titulo': titulo,
                'dica': dica,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#titulo').val('');
                $('#dica').val('');
                $('#display_area').append(response);                
            }
        });
    });
});

<textarea type="text" name="dica" id="dica" class="summernote"  class="form-control"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote();
});
```

Eu executei sem o ajax e deu tudo certo, pelo que eu percebi me parece que não da pra passar tag HTML via ajax!

Answer (score 2):

Ao digitar o texto via summernote ele não será inserido no `<textarea>`, mas sim no editor gerado, então ao tentar pegar do textarea com `.val` ele irá retornar vazio.

Para pegar do summernote use a API deles conforme é indicado na documentação: https://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api

Exemplo:

```
var dica = $('<seu elemento>').summernote('code'); //Pega o conteudo HTML gerado
```

Teste:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = $("#editor");
    editor.summernote();
    
    $("#getText").click(function () {
        console.log( editor.summernote('code') );
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>


<textarea id="editor"></textarea>

<button id="getText">Ver texto</button>
```

Comment: Guilherme, fiz do jeito que você me falou, porém no meu console ele me retorna um Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @MarcosPereira isso deve ser outro problema, tem algum link online disto?

Comment: Guilherme, não tenho não, eu estou rodando via wamp.

Comment: @MarcosPereira manda o código inteiro do HTML e do Ajax no pastebin.com e depois coloca o link aqui nos comentários pra eu ver

Comment: Ta ai Guilherme: https://pastebin.com/YGVXZGMa

Answer (score 1):

O Ajax envia normalmente o conteúdo do `textarea` usado pelo Summernote, e no *backend*, por exemplo PHP, o conteúdo do `textarea` é recebido pelo seu `name`, como em qualquer elemento de formulário, com `$_POST['dica'];`.

Vejo que nesta parte `$('#dica').val('');` do *response* do Ajax você deseja limpar o texto no editor, porém isto apenas limpará o conteúdo do `textarea`.

Para limpar o texto do editor do Summernote (versões mais recentes) você pode usar:

```
$("#dica").summernote("reset");
```

Logo, seu código ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#submit_btn', function(){
        var titulo = $('#titulo').val();
        var dica = $('#dica').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'salvar_dica.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'save': 1,
                'titulo': titulo,
                'dica': dica,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#titulo').val('');
                $('#dica')
                .val('')  // apaga o texto do textarea usado pelo summernote
                .summernote("reset"); // apaga o texto do editor
                $('#display_area').append(response);                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**Exemplo funcional**](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t3.php)

Comment: **RESOLVIDO!!!**

Comment: Olá MArcos! Marque a resposta que resolveu o problema para que a pergunta não fique em aberto. Obg!

Comment: É só clicar em ✔️ ao lado esquerdo da resposta. 

Answer (score 0):

textarea não retorna no `.val()`, use:

```
var dica = $('#dica').text();
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w27zq98j/

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o problema é em usar com [summernote](https://summernote.org), eu expliquei na resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291138/3635